# Show database result where INNER JOIN doesn't find another result

Tags: outer-join

I have 2 tables  with products.

Like:

```
id | link | name 
1 | 200 | apple
2 | 300 | Pineapple
3 | 450 | Banana
```

And

```
id | link | price
1 | 200 | 2.00
2 | 300 | 2.50
3 | 450 | 4.00
4 | 500 | 1000
```

The tables can be joined by link.
With a (inner) JOIN I can show the 3 products incl the prices.

But is there a way to show:

```
4 | 500 | 1000
```

So I can clean my table?

I think it has something to do with Full OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.link = B.link
```

But now I see everything from both tables and I don't need the correspondence (is that the right English word?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an OUTER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 RIGHT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.link = tab2.link
```

Please note that the INNER JOIN actually performs an intersection between the two tables. When you want to see results from one side of the join that doesn't match any of the rows on the other side of the join, you use outer (right, left or full) joins (the not-matched side's columns will be padded with nulls).

Comment: Sorry edited my starting post.
But when I use this I see all the results.

Comment: @Coolen Maybe it would help if you'd show me what is the intended result and how does it differ from the result you get when running the FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: THe result should be:
4 | 500 | 1000

Comment: @Coolen So you want to see all rows in `Table_B` that don't have a match in `Table_A`? Then you could it better like `SELECT * FROM Table_B WHERE link NOT IN (SELECT link FROM Table_A)`

Comment: Yes and also all the rows in table_a that don't have a match in table B

I think something like SELECT *
FROM Table_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.link = B.link WHERE A.link IS Emtpy
OR B.link IS Empty
But empty does not work, neither does 0

Comment: I Think I found the answer.

Please let me know if there are any loopholes

SELECT 
 * 
FROM
 Table_A A 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
 Table_B B 
  ON
 A.link = B.link 
WHERE 
 A.link IS NULL 
OR 
 B.link IS NULL

Comment: Yes, this is one way of doing it.

Comment: OK thank you, is this a good way to solve it or are there better ways?